# How to remove all null values from a generic typed array?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a class called ArraySort which is generically typed

```
public class ArraySort<E> {
    public void bubbleSort(E[] data) {...}
}
```

which takes in a type when initiating it

```
ArraySort<Integer> ArraySort = new ArraySort<Integer>();
```

This class supports different sorting algorithms as such, but whenever an array is inputted with null values in it

```
int[] arr = {3, 1, 5, null};
ArraySort.bubbleSort(arr);
```

My code errors out with a null pointer exception. I already tried to use a method from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002264/removing-unfilled-values-or-null-values-from-array-of-string-in-java), but this didn't work due to a 'java.lang.ArrayStoreException'.

```
public E[] clean(E[] v) {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>(Arrays.asList(v));
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    return (E[]) list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```

So my question is how do I remove all null values from a generically typed Array?

Comment: If you follow the options in the duplicate link, you won't have to remove the `null` values, thereby affecting the state of your data, when you sort.  Instead, just tell Java how to handle those nulls while sorting.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked perfectly <3